# $| A\cap B| = |A \cup B|$ and $A$ is different from $B \implies A \cup B$ infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the power of $|A\cap B|$ equals to the power of $|A \cup B|$ and the sets $A,B$ are different, $\implies A \cup B$ is infinite.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 3):

If $A \cup B$ is finite then $A$ and $B$ are finite. And since $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B$, you get $A \cup B=A \cap B$. Hence $A \subseteq A \cup B = A \cap B\subseteq B$, conversely $B \subseteq A \cup B = A \cap B\subseteq A$ and the sets $A$ and $B$ are equal. No group structure needed.

Comment: why do you assume that AUB=AnB, ?

Comment: Daniel, I am not assuming that the union and intersection are equal. Since $A \cup B$ is finite and it has the same cardinality as its subset $A \cap B$, it follows that they must be equal. Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If $A\neq B$ then $A\cap B$ is a proper subset of $A\cup B$; can a finite set be equipotent to any of its *proper* subsets?